# Pivot returns null inside a Laravel Nova custom rule function but not outside it

Tags: laravel, validation, eloquent, laravel-nova

I am setting up a custom validation rule for a `BelongsToMany` field in Laravel Nova to look up in the pivot table and compare with the entered value. It uses  a function which is 'shared' with other fields of the same resource.

I am using the following code in the resource `Delegation`:

```
BelongsToMany::make('Authorities')
                ->fields(function ()
                {
                    return [

                        Help::make('Your Limit', "Your own limit for this authority is {$this->displayYourLimit()}. You can only delegate to the limit of your authority."),

                        Number::make('Delegated Limit ($M)', 'delegated_limit')

                            ->rules('required', function ($attribute, $value, $fail)
                            {
                                if ($value > $this->displayYourLimit())
                                {
                                    return $fail('Your value is too high');
                                }
                                …
```

The function in question is:

```
public function displayYourLimit()
        {
            $id1 = DB::table('delegations')->where('user_id', auth()->user()->id)->value('id');
            $id2 = $this->pivot['authority_id']; //This returns null inside the validation rule but not the Help field
            $result = DB::table('authority_delegation')->where('delegation_id', '=', $id1)->where('authority_id', '=', $id2)->value('delegated_limit');

            return $result;
        }
```

The function spans two tables in the database - `delegations`, which has a model `Delegation` and a pivot from `BelongsToMany` relationship with another model `Authority`. The pivot table is called `authority_delegation`.

`$id1` returns the value of the `id` column of the `delegations` table for the currently logged in user. This works fine.

`$id2` should return the value of the `delegation_id` column of the `authority_delegation` pivot table for the currently viewed `Authority`resource attached to `Delegation` resource. It is basically 26 in the following url `http://localhost:8000/nova/resources/delegations/2/edit-attached/authorities/26?viaRelationship=authorities` that I am trying to get.

Finally, `$result` returns the value of the `delegated_limit` column of the `authority_delegation` where two first columns' values match. This also works fine provided `$id2` sends correct value.

I expect the function to return a float which can be used both for display in the Help field and validation in the Number field. However, while working in the Help field perfectly, it does not work in validation (expected validation has no effect after `required`. Through testing, I see that it returns `null` when getting the `$id2` from the pivot within the validation rule function. I am attaching a picture to illustrate. In the image, green circle shows that the necessary value is displayed correctly in one field, red circle show that it does not pass validation correctly.

[Illustration of pivot returning null inside a Laravel Nova custom rule function but not outside it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xUAhm.jpg)

But why does it work in one field and not another?

I have spent afternoon trying to figure it out. I tried converting to array, to object etc with no effect. If I can get the `id` of the currently viewed resource - that elusive 26 - in any other way, I would love to know!

I have relevant relationships set up in respective `Authority` and `Delegation` models:

```
public function authorities()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Authority::class, 'authority_delegation')->withPivot('delegated_limit', 'further_delegatable', 'master_delegated_limit', 'authority_id', 'delegation_id')->withTimestamps();
    }

and 

public function delegations()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Delegation::class, 'authority_delegation')->withPivot('delegated_limit', 'further_delegatable', 'master_delegated_limit', 'authority_id', 'delegation_id')->withTimestamps();
    }
```

All suggestions are very welcome!

Comment: Elaborate a bit on `$id2 = $this->pivot['authority_id'];` Where does it come from?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your willingness to help! I have added more explanation of the offending function and image of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case someone has the same problem this is how I solved it:

One cannot use `$this` in a closure, PHP documentation is very specific about this. See here for more details https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php

However, it is possible to use `$request` in the closure. So I just replaced the pivot table with a dedicated model and used `use ($request)` in the validation rule like so:

```
Number::make('Delegated Limit')
                ->updateRules('required', function ($attribute, $value, $fail) use ($request) {
                        $id1 = DB::table('delegations')->where('user_id', auth()->user()->id)->value('id');
                        $id2 = $request->authority;
                        $result = DB::table('issuances')->where('delegation_id', '=', $id1)->where('authority_id', '=', $id2)->value('delegated_limit');

                        if ($value > $result)
                        {
                            return $fail('Your value is too high.');
                        }
                    }
```

And it worked just fine.